# Get value by key inside a Map<String, Map<String, Double>> JSP

Tags: java, jsp, dictionary, hashmap, jstl

I have a

```
Map<String, Map<String, Double>>
```

and I'd like to get the Double value by some given keys. I've found that it can be done using "c:foreach" but I want to find some values, I don't want to iterate all of them. It would be something like:

```
myMap['myKey']['myAnotherKey']
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<c:out value="${myMap['myKey']['myAnotherKey']}"/>
```

Comment: My god...I tried the same thing before asking and I just found out that those keys had no value...Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if you know  the keys

```
Double val = myMap.get(myKey).get(myAnotherkey);
```